# Connection of MVC3 database to azure cloud server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, azure

I have tried connecting my webapp database to the azure cloud server using a connectionstring (provided by azure) from the web.config. But theres always an error that says **"Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0."**

Anyone encountered this error before? Please help.

connection string below :

```
<add name="SQLAzureConnection"
        connectionString="Server=tcp:mnftprvzdk.database.windows.net,1433;Database=mydb;User ID=user;Password=pass;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Are you connecting to SQL AZURE?
Could you post the connectionstring (without the full servername here)? Maybe you're cutting off something!

Comment: That didn't solve the problem. I still get the same error.

Comment: How are you using the Connection string?
Can you supply a sample of your code?

Answer (score 1):

The user name should be **user@machinename**, (without the FULL DNS).

So in this case **user@mnftprvzdk**.

The format is:

```
Server=tcp:[serverName].database.windows.net;Database=myDataBase;
User ID=[LoginForDb]@[serverName];Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;
```